# Caching of blocks for anonymous user

Tags: 8, blocks, caching

I have a little probleme with my cache block.

This is my build function :

```
return [
  '#markup' => time(),
  '#cache' => [
    'max-age' => 10
  ]
];
```

I found this specification for block cache.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 20;
  }
```

Because in parent class we have `$max_age = Cache::PERMANENT;`

So, when I'm connected my rendered cache refresh each 10 seconds.
But when I'm a anonymous user my rendered block never change.

I don't find the solution.

Big pipe isn't install, I have aggregations css and js but I don't have max age in admin/config/development/performance.

Finnaly I want a block without cache because this block will rendered message with close button. When the user click on the close button, I set a cookie for return an empty bluid in my block.

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: In your custom block template, are you rendering the `{{ content }}` variable in full? If not, cache tags may not be bubbling up.

Comment: I havn't custom block template for moment. I rendered also #markup with #cache key

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to worry about the values which are set for cache max-age in other places, because when these are merged the lower time that you have set wins.

But you can't control with max-age the page cache for anonymous users. You have to use `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();` in the block build method to disable the page cache or you can simply uninstall the module *Internal Page Cache* if you plan to use the block on all pages.

> but I don't have max age in admin/config/development/performance

You should set this to the same max-age to control the browser cache and proxies.

Comment: I'm convinced you're a wizard.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/2352009 for the core issue that is trying to change this.

Answer (score 0):

[Cache Control Override](https://www.drupal.org/project/cache_control_override) plugin intends to solve the problem with an anonymous user cache control.
After installation, both methods will work:

```
return array(
  '#markup' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
  '#cache' => array('max-age' => 10).
);
```

or

```
public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 10;
}
```