# Disable cache a custom block for anonymous user

Tags: 8, caching

I have a custom block, it displays in every pages with dynamic data calculates in every refresh, How can I disable cache for this block for anonymous users?

I try with:

```php
public function build() {
  return [
    '#markup' => time(),
    '#cache' => [
      'max-age' => 0,
    ],
  ];
}
```

It won't work.

**Edit:**
I don't want to disable the cache for the entire page, I just need a specific block not to be cache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent a particular page being cached?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151254/how-can-i-prevent-a-particular-page-being-cached)

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228485/caching-of-blocks-for-anonymous-user

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely disable caching for the block, use this function in your block class:

```
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }
```

I've never found in the documentation why

```
'#cache' => [
      'max-age' => 0,
    ],
```

doesn't work with blocks but, like you discovered, it doesn't seem to.